# How to shift the entire page to the right of the inserted side panel?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to inject a side panel onto the current page (for building bookmarklet). However, it seems to simply overlap the left portion of the page, what I was aiming for is shifting the whole page to the right of this inserted panel.

```
  //initilaize 
  var sidebar;
  $('body').css({
    'padding-right': '350px'
  });
  sidebar = $("<div id='sidebar'></div>");
  sidebar.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'left': '0px',
    'top': '0px',
    'z-index': 9999,
    'width': '290px',
    'height': '100%',
    'background-color': 'blue'  // Confirm it shows up
  });
  $('body').append(sidebar);
```

Here's a jsfiddle of what's happening, it's covering up the page, I need for it to shift to accomodate for the sidepanel.

http://jsfiddle.net/DT3k7/

Comment: You are going to need to provide some relevant markup/CSS.. it could be anything. An example would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the css of the body to be `padding-left` or `margin-left` instead of right.

```
$('body').css({
    'padding-left': '350px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `margin-left` to the body when you append the sidebar.  Not sure where the `padding-right` is coming from.  This worked on the jsfiddle for me.

```
  $('body').ready(function(){
     $('body').append(sidebar)   
     $('body').css({
        'margin-left':'290px'
     });
  });
```

You could even add a cool slider effect with JQuery UI!